# Join threads in a() that were created in a previous call of a(). Is this possible?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, join, pthreads

**SOLVED / SHORT ANSWER: Yes you can. Bug was somewhere else. Read on if you want to know where it was.**

I have to process items (do calculations that are independent between items). Items are processed in a function a();

What i want to do is whenever a() is called, create a new thread with all a()'s processing code in it, and immediately exit a(). Next time a() will be called (is called immediately by the caller which i don't have access to), will again create a new thread and terminate. When 8 consequent calls have been made (i have 8 cores), inside a() join the 8 previous threads and go on...

Is this possible? Can i join inside a() threads that have been created in a previous call of a()?

My program, while it runs perfectly for 1 thread, it faults in any other number.

=================================================================================

ADDED CODE FOR YOU TO SEE:

First of all. I don't have access to the function that calls a(). if no threading is involved, caller waits until a() finishes it's calculations, and then calls it again providing the next x,y* s. What i want to do is doing parallel the calculations of 8 a()s. If a() can start its calculations and return (create a thread and exit), caller will call a() again with the new x,y* while the old are still being calculated. This is the concept. Calculations of every x,y* pair is totally independent to any other pair.

```
int counter = 0;
pthread_t threads[8]; //i have 8 cores
thread_args args[8]; //arguments that pass to the threads
int res[8]; //threads store their results here

void a(int x, int y*) { //a() is being called by caller immediately after it returns with a new pair of x,y*
    args[counter].x = x; //struct thread_args has x,y,my_counter
    args[counter].y = y;
    args[counter].my_counter = counter;
    pthread_create(&threads[counter], NULL, calculate_xy, (void *)&args[counter]);
    //calculate_xy stores results in res[args->my_counter]     

    if(++counter != 8)
        return;

    //it reaches here every 8th call of a(); (total number of a() calls is an exact multiple of 8)
    counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);

    //GO ON... append the 8 results to a text and go on...
}//end a()
```

Comment: Can you please show _how_ you create your threads? I.e. the code of this function `a`. Seeing the code helps much more than reading a description of it.

Comment: This description *sounds* wrong, but I think it's more of a language translation issue.  As @JoachimPileborg said, post some code so we can see what is actually happening.

Comment: "*Can i join threads created in a previous call of a()*", yes, I'd say conceptual this could work.

Comment: The thread function is really only dependent on two int arguments?  There's no other state that `calculate_xy()` depends on? Is this a simplification for posting in a question, or does that code that crashes really only use two ints?

Comment: @Michael Burr Arguments are the only things simplified. Yes, they are not two integers. It is an integer and a char*. But i don't see any dependencies. What i need to know is if this code should work as described. If it should, then i must start looking for mistakes at some other place.

Comment: What does the `char *` point to? If it's pointing to data that's being modified or freed before the thread finishes operating on it, that's almost certainly your problem.

Comment: And with this I should mention the general rule: Please do not post "fake code". If you're posting a code example that's simplified from the original code that failed, you should make sure you can reproduce the failure with the simplified code. If you can't, then you're giving us worthless information; the bug (or at least part of the bug) is in the part of the code that you've omitted or simplified away!

Comment: Create a copy of the character array the character pointer (you are mentioning in your comment) points to and pass a reference to this copy on to the thread.

Comment: Thank you a lot @R..
Problem was that at every new call of a(), caller function reused where char* used to point. So what i needed to do was copy with strcpy the current content of char* at the begining of a(). 

It is my first time posting here. What do i need to do now? Do i need to write the solution somewere or it is trivial and the question should be romoved?

Comment: There's no need to remove the question. You should post what you did as an answer, and then folks can look at it and comment on whether it's complete/correct or still has race conditions.

Comment: I think i did it. Thank you again

Comment: If you have solved your own problem, please answer your own question and accept it instead of updating your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my original question is yes.
You can join threads in a function that were created in a previous call of this same function.

The bug in my code was that the place where y* pointed, was reused inside caller, every time a() was called. So, while i thought that previously created threads were still doing their job correctly, they were not because during their life, the place where y* argument was pointing was being repeatedly rewritten, at every new a() call from the caller with the contents of the next x,y* pair messing threads' calculations.

Thank you all. You guided me to solution.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, whatever the bug in your code, this is a bad design. Your function `a()` has global state (the past-created threads and the number created so far) which would be bad enough in a single-threaded program, but in a multi-threaded program, things could go very wrong if multiple threads could simultaneously call `a()`. Even if not, there are many reasons to avoid global state:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FRm3VPhseI

A much better design would be for the `a()` function to take an extra argument, a pointer to a structure containing the counter and an array of `pthread_t` values for all the threads created so far. Then, the "state of `a()`" would not be global state, but would be state belonging to the part of the program using `a()`.

As for why your program is crashing right now, it's hard to say without seeing any code. I suspect you're either calling `a()` from multiple threads without synchronization, or just have a careless error/typo somewhere in your array indexing...